# Why does ifort -warn all throw errors on interface mismatch?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-warnings, intel-fortran

Here is some example code:

```
! Author: Svetlana Tkachenko svetlana@members.fsf.org
! License: GPLv3 or later

subroutine myprint(var) 
!    integer :: var 
!    print *, 'Hi, my ', var 
end subroutine 

module testing 
   type triangle 
      integer :: point(3) 
   end type 
end module 

program main 
   use testing 
   type(triangle) :: mytriangle 
   mytriangle%point(1)=5 
   call myprint(mytriangle%point(1)) 
end program
```

it works fine with `ifort -c file.f90`, but `ifort -warn all -c file.f90` results in an error:

```
blah.f90(4): warning #6717: This name has not been given an explicit type.   [VAR]
subroutine myprint(var) 
-------------------^
blah.f90(4): remark #7712: This variable has not been used.   [VAR]
subroutine myprint(var) 
-------------------^
blah.f90(19): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [POINT]
   call myprint(mytriangle%point(1)) 
---------------------------^
compilation aborted for blah.f90 (code 1)
```

Why does `-warn all` throw an error? The man page specifically says that `all` *doesn't* include errors.

I know I could just fix the code, but I am trying to set up a testing suite for a legacy code base, and I want to be able to run compilation tests with warnings before I start making code changes.

Comment: You can (should) ask the vendor at the officisl support forum for the reasons for their specific behaviour.

Comment: I just assume you are aware that `var` is implicitly `real` in the subroutine...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option `-warn all` includes the option `-warn interfaces` inciting interface checking for external procedures where such interfaces can be determined.  This is often for interfaces generated from external procedures in separate files compiled with the option `-gen-interfaces`.

It is this option `-warn interfaces` that is responsible for the error message.  This is able to check the interface of the external subroutine because that subroutine is in the same file as the program which references it.  You have two options, then:

- have the external subroutine in a distinct file, not compiled with `-gen-interfaces`;
- don't use `-warn interfaces`.

For this latter, you can use

```
ifort -warn all -warn nointerfaces ...
```

to have all other warnings but the interface checking.

Preferable to each of those, however, is to have the matching interface.  It should be noted, then, that

```
subroutine myprint(var) 
!    integer :: var
end subroutine
```

and

```
subroutine myprint(var) 
     integer :: var
end subroutine
```

are two very different things in the presence of default implicit typing rules.  They may have the same ultimate effect with having no executable statements (etc.) but the characteristics are quite different.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It still seems like a bug that this is reported as an error, and not a warning, right?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug in the compiler.  You are calling a procedure with an implicit interface and you are asking the compiler to check (with the implied `-warn interfaces` option) whether the interfaces match.  It does this, in a sense (I gather) by pretending that the interface was explicit (see the documentation, including around the `-gen-interfaces` option, and look at the generated module file: it acts as though a module is involved), which indeed makes this an error rather than a warning.  Yes, I can see that having this as a warning would be nice ... cont

Comment: ... and there are many times when various calls become much simpler when hacking interfaces can be done in a certain way, but the compiler allows you the choice of whether you make this an error or not: you could, in your "warning phase" turn this on, and then recompile without the interface checking as the next step.

Comment: In summary: your code _is_ strictly erroneous, and the compiler is being nice by going beyond its normal duty to detect that for you.  But only because you asked it to.  [If I look at nagfor, for example, one has to make an effort to allow passing of what it knows to be bad calls.]

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, I guess. I was hoping that I'd be able to get as many warnings as possible with a successful compilation, so that I could track progress a little better, but I guess it doesn't matter too much. The `nointerfaces` option removes that error, but maybe I'll leave it on, and just aim at fixing that particular problem first. Thanks!

Comment: As Vladimir F commented earlier, the Intel forum may be the best place to inquire about reasoning or justification - I'm only speaking for my intuition.  Your request certainly seems reasonable and perhaps the experts there have alternative thoughts.