# gfortran : check subroutine argument list (if call match definition)

Tags: fortran, arguments, gfortran

I'm debugging fortran program with gfortran using `-g -Og -fcheck=all`

It still does not report errors, that the number and type of arguments in call differs from the definition

**e.g. it pass things like this without errors:**

Definition:

```
subroutine assemble_2c(iforce, itheory, natoms)
        integer, intent(in) :: iforce
        integer, intent(in) :: itheory
        integer, intent(in) :: natoms
...
end subroutine
```

use

```
call assemble_2c()
```

**also this:**

```
subroutine assemble_2c()
...
end subroutine
```

use

```
call assemble_2c(iforce, itheory, natoms)
```

comming from C/C++ (Java, python... basically any other language) ... this seems to me as perhaps the most basic thing which compiler should check, so I'm really dismayed it does not.

Comment: What errors do you think it should detect? You don't show enough code for anyone to be certain that there _are_ errors.  See [mre]. Either way, `-fcheck=all` is for run-time checks, whereas errors with interfaces would typically be compile-time errors.

Comment: It should tell me that I call it with different number of arguments, then I define it, or vice versa. That the call interface differs from the definition. ... how it is not obvious form what I wrote ?

Comment: It's not at all obvious, because: the arguments could be optional; the names may be generic; those subroutines may not be the ones called at runtime; the interfaces may be implicit when referenced; control flow may mean that the calls don't happen; etc.

Comment: OK, I want to check it in compile time if possible (irrespective of control-flow).
ad "optional / generic" - OK, I don't know much about that features of fortran? But I want to enforce solid (dependable) interface of subroutines, otherwise the debugging is a hell.

Comment: In that case abandon external procedures and use modules. They were created 30 years ago exactly for this purpose. If you use external procedures, you get what you are asking for. No, without a proper include file a C compiler cannot check the interface either, it is the same.

Comment: I'm just debugging old code, I cannot change the whole structure

Comment: Placing old procedures into a module is often pretty trivial - effort that takes minutes, not hours. Anyway, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740299/why-does-ifort-warn-all-throw-errors-on-interface-mismatch?rq=1 and try `-Wall` `-Wextra` `-Wsurprising` or whatever individual options you can find. Try enabling `-flto`.

Comment: ad C header files ... is it possible to do it in similar way? i.e. keep the function body (=implementation) where it is (own .f90 file) but put the header (interface) into a module file ?

Comment: Yes you can with a bit of extra work - but it is much easier and less error prone to stick the procedure in a module. Fortran /= C.

Comment: That said you might look into the -gen-interface option on the Intel compiler, especially because at the moment you can get it for free as part of the oneapi stuff. Never used it mysefl but it might do what you want (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/compiler-diagnostic-options/gen-interfaces.html)